# Finding and removing duplicates that meets multiple criteria while ignorning own cell in search

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a VBA script that will merge two sheets together and then delete all the duplicates that meet a certain criteria. First, it only removes entries that are duplicates and has no data in column E and column F. I think my code works mostly, except that it includes the cell it is trying to find in the COUNTIF search and so it always returns a value of 1. I want to have the countif search in the range and exclude the current cell in the for loop. I'm totally open to the idea of reworking the for loop that removes duplicates if there is an easier way to go about it.

Thanks!

```
Public Sub HMBMerge()

Dim sheet1 As String
Dim sheet2 As String
Dim comp1 As String
Dim comp2 As String
Dim sheet1Len As Long
Dim sheet2Len As Long
Dim t As Long
Dim cell As Range
Dim mergeRange As Range

sheet1 = Application.InputBox("Type name of sheet 1", "Sheet 1", , , , , , 2)
sheet2 = Application.InputBox("Type name of sheet 2", "Sheet 2", , , , , , 2)
HMBmergename = Application.InputBox("Type name of merged output sheet name", "Output Sheet Name", , , , , , 2)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Worksheets(sheet1).Activate
sheet1Len = Worksheets(sheet1).Range("B1", Range("B1").End

(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    Worksheets(sheet2).Activate
    sheet2Len = Worksheets(sheet2).Range("B1", Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = HMBmergename

    Worksheets(sheet1).Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet1).Range("A1", Range("I1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1)).Copy Destination:=Worksheets(HMBmergename).Range("A1")
    Worksheets(sheet2).Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet2).Range("A1", Range("I2").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1)).Offset(1, 0).Copy Destination:=Worksheets(HMBmergename).Cells(sheet1Len + 1, 1)

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(HMBmergename).Activate
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(HMBmergename).Columns("A:J").AutoFit
    Worksheets(HMBmergename).Range("A1", Range("I1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1)).Sort Key1:=Range("C1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes


    For t = Worksheets(HMBmergename).Range("B1", Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets(HMBmergename).Range("B1", Range("B1").End(xlDown)), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(HMBmergename).Cells(t, "B").Value) > 0 And Worksheets(HMBmergename).Cells(t, "E") = "" And Worksheets(HMBmergename).Cells(t, "F") = "" Then
            MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets(HMBmergename).Range("B1", Range("B1").End(xlDown)), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(HMBmergename).Cells(t, "B").Value)
            Worksheets(HMBmergename).Rows(t).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: Are the duplicates in one row? Have you looked up the `Range.RemoveDuplicates` method?

Comment: Then how about `countif()>1`?

Answer (score 0):

I know it isn't the prettiest (but then again, expected from a first time VBA project), but I got around my issues by making two if statements. One to check for the blanks, and then one that checks to see if there is a duplicate.

```
For t = Worksheets(HMBmergename).Range("B1", Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
    If Worksheets(HMBmergename).Cells(t, "E") = "" And Worksheets(HMBmergename).Cells(t, "F") = "" Then
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets(HMBmergename).Range("B1", Range("B1").End(xlDown)), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(HMBmergename).Cells(t, "B").Value) > 1 Then
            'MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets(HMBmergename).Range("B1", Range("B1").End(xlDown)), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(HMBmergename).Cells(t, "B").Value)
            Worksheets(HMBmergename).Rows(t).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    End If
Next
```